# Error Help: Out Of Bounds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="lnewsblock">
            <p class="newsthumb">
                <img src="@Html.Raw(item.ShortImage)" width="90" height="71" alt="" /></p>
            <p class="datetxt">@Html.Raw(item.Date.Value.ToString("ddd MM.dd.yyyy"))</p>
            <h2> <a href="/resources/newsdetail?id=@Html.Raw(item.ID.ToString())">@Html.Raw(item.Title)</a></h2>
            <p class="greytxt">@Html.Raw(item.Description.Left(125))<a href="/resources/newsdetail?id=@Html.Raw(item.ID.ToString())"> more</a></p>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

The above code is causing a couple of issues.  You will notice that it is pulling  ShortImage which is fine. However, if there **isn't an image to pull**, this produces an error.  How would I fix the code to account for this?

Secondly, when it pulls the item description,  It tries to pull the first `125` characters. So **if the description is too short, this also produces an error.**  How would I structure the code to account for this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.NewsModel.RetrieveCollectionOfNews(NewsType ShowType) in D:\SVN\LbyEgglw\LbyEgglw.WebApp\Mvc\Models\NewsModel.cs:53
   SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers.NewsController.Index() in D:\SVN\LbyEgglw\LbyEgglw.WebApp\Mvc\Controllers\NewsController.cs:29
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.ControllerWrapper.Execute() +133
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.Proxy.MvcControllerProxy.ExecuteController() +2620
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4201


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Comment: That's a pretty unfortunate situation you're in, having to fix something you don't understand.

Comment: yea I agree...especially being a Razor MVC ASP application.  I wonder how this fell into your lap.  At any rate what you are looking to do is basic error-handling.  I'll post something short and sweet below.

Comment: do you have the stack trace btw?

Comment: well this is actually sort-of front-end development =P...what is your familiarity with the languages presented here? notably the HTML and C#

Comment: @MikeHometchko One sec, let me go produce it, and I'll post it here.

Comment: inside of the @foreach why can you not check for a IsNullOrEmpty or null value prior to moving forward with assigning your image src..? will this link help you to understand what you can do in regards to your current code http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for the link that definitely helps me understand the Syntax better.

Comment: not a problem I don't user `Razor` but I am familiar with reading the code.. looks like someone has provided you an excellent answer to help solve your problem. personally makes me wonder if the `Vendor themselves know how to code let alone fix code` I would suggest to the people you work with to start developing internally vs wasting resources on a `3rd party that of which is not willing to provide support for something that they have written and or developed`

Comment: @MikeHometchko Posting the stack trace right now

Comment: @Russell edit your post and put it there if you could so it's readily available for anybody taking a look at the question :)

Comment: @MikeHometchko Posted, and as I said below I'm also interested in exploring the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a real hack, because you should never put logic like this in your View, but you *could* do this;

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="lnewsblock">

            <p class="newsthumb">
            @if(item.ShortImage != null)
            {
                <img src="@Html.Raw(item.ShortImage)" width="90" height="71" alt="" /></p>
            }
            </p>

            <p class="datetxt">
                @Html.Raw(item.Date.Value.ToString("ddd MM.dd.yyyy"))
            </p>

            <h2><a href="/resources/newsdetail?id=@Html.Raw(item.ID.ToString())">@Html.Raw(item.Title)</a></h2>

            <p class="greytxt">
            @if(item.Description.Length >= 125)
            {
                @Html.Raw(item.Description.Left(125))<a href="/resources/newsdetail?id=@Html.Raw(item.ID.ToString())"> more</a>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw(item.Description)<a href="/resources/newsdetail?id=@Html.Raw(item.ID.ToString())"> more</a>
            }
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

What should really be done is that the "Model" portion of this should not allow you to receive data that won't be acceptable to the View.

Comment: yea thats why I asked for the stack trace...I upvoted for the effort but I don't suggest error handling logic like this in a view

Comment: @MikeHometchko Thanks!  I figured, given the OPs circumstances, it would be nice to have something that "just works" for now.  I know this is awful code =P

Comment: Thanks a lot Jadarnel27, this is what I was looking for.  @MikeHometchko I am interested into at least exploring the proper way to do this as well, so I have included the stack trace in my OP above.

Comment: Would using a HTML helper that used similar logic for building the image HTML be better? And for the Description, using an GET only property in a view model that contained logic for showing the correct description?

Comment: Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "p" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?


Source Error:


Line 31:             else
Line 32:             {
Line 33:                 </p>
Line 34:             }
Line 35:             <p class="datetxt">@Html.Raw(item.Date.Value.ToString("ddd MM.dd.yyyy"))</p>-----------------I think I can fix this by moving the </p> tag out of the if statement.--------------

Comment: @Russell I believe you could fix that by at least adding something inside the paragraph tags in the event that the else closure is called.  Try adding &nbsp; (HTML-encoded 'space' character) infront of the </p> tag.

Comment: I updated the post @Russell.  It seems cleaner probably to just leave the p tags out of the if-else blocks altogther.

Comment: hey @Russell...don't forget to mark the most useful answer to you as complete!  I'm sure jadarnel27 would like that! :)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Thank you this worked great, it turned out the image was actually creating problems in the Model itself.  Since we don't have the capacity to edit and recompile the code I found another work around for this inside of SiteFinity.. However, this definitely solved the character length issue.

Comment: @MikeHometchko, already done :D, also I'm reviewing your answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your stack trace doesn't help much (at least, not me).  The system developed has a lot going on in this particular part of the program and without seeing it's code I can't give you a concrete answer or suggestion for this problem.  That being said, I'd like to share with you an alternative approach for your issue.

A while back I needed to find an efficient way to render images with anchor tags around them to serve as image links or buttons.  While it is feasible to do this in hard-coded HTML...the images were often dynamic so I found a more programmatic approach by extending the MVC framework with a little snippet.  Here it is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, string action, object routeValues, string imagePath, string alt)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // build the <img> tag
        var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
        string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

        // build the <a> tag
        var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, routeValues));
        anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
        string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
    }
```

It's not the most robust extension, but it serves my purpose, and it could serve you as well.  Writing variables into HTML attributes (eg: src for images) is dangerous as anyone with basic HTML knowledge could potentially hack their way into your backend with a small adjustment.  This is the main concern I had about **jadarnel27**'s solution as it keeps your variables in places I don't like them.

This simple extension allows for the dynamic, safe creation of linked images in your views with a simple one-liner:

```
<p class="site-title">@Html.ActionImage("Index", null, "~/Images/logo_sm.jpg", "Index")</p>
```

If you were to adapt this extension for your programs needs, you could do all error-handling on the backend quite similarly to **jadarnel27**'s solution.  This would both fix your original problem, and make the application more secure.

Unfortunately, you mentioned that this is not your area of expertise and, by the looks of it, you'd need to make some pretty massive and sweeping changes to the application if it is all coded like the snippet you've posted above.  At any rate, I hope this at least helps you and your company make an informed decision on moving forward.

Comment: I'm actually going to save this and present it to my supervision.  ESPECIALLY since you noted the security concerns (which given the type of company I work for, is priorty number 1).  I can't claim that I could re-create this on my own, but I understand the syntax enough to see what it is doing. Thanks for taking your time to write this out, I'll keep you updated if we implement this.

Comment: @Russell I'm glad to help out!

Comment: @MikeHometchko So I wanted to update you on this.  I brought this up with my supervision and we ended up kicking it back to our development vendor.  They came back with:                                                               "-These controls are read-only controls, just fetches data from backend. 
-These controls doesn’t have fields to input injection scripts.
-These controls doesn’t save any data to backend .
-Model is tightly bounded to View.

so there is no risk involved.
" Any thoughts?

Comment: @Russell I cannot speak for the integrity of the data or the security measures in place.  The reasoning is sound, but in practice I just try to stay away from the methodologies they use.  I am not a 15-year MVC expert so my advice should be taken with a grain of salt.  Before taking any drastic measures with the outsourced firm, perhaps your company should look into a third-party penetration-testing service.  In fact, being that this application was not developed internally...I strongly recommend doing so just to verify the applications security.